Blender transforms suddenly multiplies mouse movements
I think I have presses some shortcut or accidentally changed some settings, but in my current project, whenever I am zoomed in too much and try to move a vertex for example the movement happens in extremely high increments, making any fine grained control impossible (even pressing G and then arrow keys is too much).
I checked in an older backup save, the issue is not apparent there:

Here is the same operation on the same piece in the current save:

Here is an additional screenshot with the rest of the UI (I am happy to add additional screenshots with settings if any information is needed)

Again, this seems only to be apparent when zoomed in quite a bit. Any idea, which setting is causing this behavior? I wasn't able to find any solution so far.

Your transform pivot point is set to 3D Cursor. Where is the 3D Cursor in your scene? It may be in an awkward position in relation to your mouse and viewport and cause unexpected movements. Try moving the 3D Cursor somewhere inside your viewport or set another transform pivot point setting maybe.


Oh boy, that was it. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy (also I change the pivot point quite a lot, but usually it is wanted. Must have accidentally  swiped the mouse with the .-menu open at one point)
